# how to run multiple nested calls with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My web application is developed on Ruby on Rails environment.

I want to execute the same set of actions by the controller, a certain number of times, that's determined by 3 inputs from the user. These are a_count, b_count, and c_count, so the total number of calls should be a_count*b_count*c_count.

Requests are sent to the server every 100ms.

I tried this Javascript code, but it is not working

```
function runBatch() {
    var timestamp = Date.now();
    var i_a = 0;
    var i_b = 0;
    var i_c = 0;
    var a_count = parseInt(document.getElementById('a_id').value);
    var b_count = parseInt(document.getElementById('b_id').value);
    var c_count = parseInt(document.getElementById('c_id').value);
    var aVar=setInterval(function() {
        var bVar=setInterval(function() {
            var cVar=setInterval(function() {
                updateFields('Batch',timestamp);
                i_c++;
                if (i_c==c_count) {
                    clearInterval(cVar);
                }
            },100);
            i_b++;
            if (i_b==b_count) {
                clearInterval(bVar);
            }
        },c_count*100);
        i_a++;
        if (i_a==a_count) {
            clearInterval(aVar);
        }
    },b_count*c_count*100);
}
```

What I am seeing is that if I have only one loop, all works as expected. But if I add the 2nd and the 3rd loops, they will execute indefinitely.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why the 3 nested setInterval ? Why not just 1 that counts up to a_count*b_count*c_count?

Comment: @FrederickCheung : thanks for your response. I have 3 nested setInterval because for each one, updateFields executes a different set of actions, so (1,1,2) is not the same thing than (1,2,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by simply making variables aVar, bVar and cVar global, and without changing anything else, as follows :

```
var aVar;
var bVar;
var cVar;
function runBatch() {
....
}
```